# How can I give a program writing access to a directory?

Tags: imagemagick

There's a program called imagemagick that can edit images.

It can save files to my home folder with out issues.

It won't save images to a folder /var/www/thumb_nails/

edit: it does work if I execute the script I have the command in. 
It just wont work when apache2 uses the script... very strange...

Comment: The reason it doesn't work specifically when apache2 runs the script is that apache2 runs as a special user account, for security reasons. [Misc]'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/143823/22949) changes the directory's ownership to `www-data` to address this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the unix permissions on the folder.

Either you set it to be owned by www-data, with :

```
chown www-data /var/www/thumb_nails/
chmod u+w /var/www/thumb_nails/
```

Or you use ACL ( a more complete permission system ) to let the user www-data ( ie, the user that apache is using ) write there

```
setfacl -m u:www-data:rw /var/www/thumb_nails/
```

Comment: THANK YOU!... for some reason I can't mark this as answered. I have to wait five minutes. I'll come back in a bit

Comment: you forgot to mark this as an answered